# Unity Vector in If Else Statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner when it comes to coding so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a boomerang mechanic for a 2d platformer where the boomerang switches directions when it reached at a certain point in which I can set it in the inspector. The way I thought about it was if I subtract the coordinates of the boomerang and the point of destination I will get the distance in between and put it in an if statement and compare to see if the boomerangs position is greater than and equal to the point so it can change its direction. However I receive this error that says

> operator cannot be applied to operands to float and vector 2.

below is my code for the boomerang:

```
public Transform Target;

public float speed; // speed it travels

public Vector2 returnDistance; // The point in where boomerang switches 
direction

private bool keepGoing = false; // Update the frame to make it keep going


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    //rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float checkDistance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, 
    returnDistance); // check the distance between two points 

    Debug.DrawLine(Target.position, transform.position, Color.red);

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || (keepGoing == true))
    {

        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime); // move 
        the boomerang to the right
        keepGoing = true;

    }

    if (checkDistance >= returnDistance)
    {
        transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime); // move 
        the boomerang to the left
        keepGoing = true;
    } 
  }
}
```

So how should I go about this so that I cant take the value I set it up in the inspector for the boomerangs turning point and put it in an if statement?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 2):

You should compare checkDistance variable to some treshhold float value (close to zero, but not 0f) — 0.1f or 0.01f etc (you should figure it out by testing).

UPD: I think I should extend my answer to clarify the problem here. You are trying to compare `float` and `[float; float]`. Obviously it does not make sense. So you should compare two float values.

If you want boomerang to fly for some fixed distance from who is throwing it, you may campare distance from your character to boomerang with some float value (max distance of throw).

Or if you want boomerang to return after it reaches some point in space you should do as I wrote at the beginning — compare distance from boomerang to that point in space with some float value (close enough to consider it boomerang did hit the target)

Comment: i.e. `returnDistance` should be a `float`, not a `Vector2` and have a small value

Comment: @Alexander than line`float checkDistance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, 
    returnDistance); // check the distance between two points` would result the similar error.

Comment: Right, he'd need a different variable for the distance then.

Comment: I see so what your saying is that i need a max distance for how far i can through the boomerang rather than a point in space

Comment: It depends on your needs. If boomerang will move away from your character for a fixed distance every time, than yes — you should compare max distance to current distance between boomerang and character,

Answer (score 1):

You said *"I'm trying to create a boomerang mechanic for a 2d platformer where the boomerang switches directions when it reached at a certain point"*. Then you can use [Vector2.sqrMagnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-sqrMagnitude.html).

Here is an example of using this vector

```
public static float SqrMagnitude(Vector2 a)
{
     return a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y;
}
```

So in your case it could be something like this

```
 Vector2 dir = P2 - P1;
 float length = dir.magnitude;
 dir -= length;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: `sqrMagnitude` is already a property of the `Vector2` class: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-sqrMagnitude.html, not that you even use the method you created...

Comment: Hi thank you for taking the time to answer I'm trying to compare the distance from the boomerangs current position to another position in which i can update in the inspector. I did what you recommended and I'm getting the same error with dir -= lengths as I had before

Answer (score -3):

```
If ((Checkdistance -  returndistance) > 0f)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because you're just doing almost the same thing as OP, trying to substract a float by Vector2. You will end up with the same error.